# Print between lines 7-13 who contain a certain string (awk script)

Tags: awk

I am trying to write a script (.awk) that will print out lines that contain a certain string between lines 7-13. I have it partially working however it prints out all lines that contain the string rather than only between 7-13.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { (NR>=7) && (NR<=13) }
/word/ {print $0}
```

the output when running

```
script.awk filename
```

is all lines that contain the word

edit:

After trying out what jeff suggested, I get this with his suggestion. /needle/ being the keyword.

Code
[image: Code]
Solved!

**The issue was that I had {print $0} on another line, used to it in other languages where I like to separate my code out**

Comment: Please [don't post](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text) images of text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've put the line restriction logic in the "BEGIN" block, which is executed *before* `awk` reads in any data. Move that logic to the main loop:

```
NR >= 7 && NR <= 13 && /word/ { print }
```

`$0` is the default `print` argument, if none is given... or, even shorter as

```
NR >= 7 && NR <= 13 && /word/
```

since `{print}` is the default action, if none is specified.
The main body of an `awk` script is of the form "pattern" "action"; you want the pattern to prefix the action that you want. Here, the pattern requires the three tests to be true, and the action to be to print the line.  Putting the `print` on a separate line means that there's no "action" when "passing" the tests, and there's no "pattern" for printing every line -- resulting in every line being printed.

Answer (score 3):

Just complementing [Jeff's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/478565/116858) with one written in `sed`:

```
sed -n '7,13 { /expression/ p; }' <file
```

This would print every line between lines 7 and 13 (inclusively) that matches the regular expression `expression`.  The default output is turned off with `-n` so only the lines explicitly printed with the `p` command will be outputted.

A direct translation of the above `sed` script into `awk`:

```
awk 'NR == 7, NR == 13 { if (/expression/) print }' <file
```

The condition `NR == 7, NR == 13` should be read as "from any input record for which `NR` is 7, to any input record for which `NR` is 13", where "input record" by default is a line and `NR` is the number of records (lines) read so far.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
awk 'NR>6&&NR<14&&/word/' file
```

Comment: This is essentially [Jeff's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/478565/116858) with the `<=` and `>=` replaced by `<` and `>` and the line numbers adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Yep, 2 bytes saved, bonus :-)